Hadoop Mapreduce word count - /tmp/user is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file
I´m new to hadoop and I need to use wordcounter for school project. Everything went fine with hadoop installation, until this error which showed when I ran the mapreducer.jar program to count word occurrences. Can somebody please explain what I need to do to fix it?
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2024-05-04 18:15:02.043]Exception from container-launch.

Container id: container_1714826590519_0010_02_000001

Exit code: 1

Exception message: '/tmp/hadoop-Natália' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.

[2024-05-04 18:15:02.047]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1.

[2024-05-04 18:15:02.047]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1.

For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://LAPTOP-2NVLK8PI:8088/cluster/app/application_1714826590519_0010 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.

. Failing the application.

2024-05-04 18:15:02,342 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0

I've searched everywhere but I didn't find any solution.

Well, this may not be the reason, but a good practice is not to use special characters in the fie names such as /tmp/hadoop-Natália
